# netlogo interaction between two turtle types

Tags: netlogo, radius

I'm new to Netlogo and I'm using it for a uni project. Basically I have created a tsunami evacuation model on a street grid and have two types of turtles, 'citizens' and 'tourists'. I have coded it so the citizens run to their nearest evacuation point when they see the tsunami and the tourists run to their nearest building. I am trying to create a 'radius' variable where if a 'citizen' sees a certain 'tourist' within a given radius they will rescue them and take them to the nearest evac point. Can anyone help?

You can see my [code so far on Netlogo commons](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/4266#model_tabs_browse_procedures).

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? There are lots of people here who can help if you ask a specific question.

Comment: Specifically I am stuck on trying to get my two agents to react with each other. I have got 360 'citizen' agents which I have coded to run to their nearest safe zone when the tsunami starts. I also have 'tourist' agents, which vary between 0 and 500, and I have coded them to run to their nearest building. What I am trying to code now is a command which will make the citizens help/attract tourists within a given radius and take them to the nearest evacuation point which would save more of them from dying. So far I have tried the 'in-cone' and 'in-radius' functions but have not had any luck.

Comment: Please show your code. Note that you can edit your question to improve it — it's better than tacking on comments.

Comment: [link](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/4266#model_tabs_browse_procedures)

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. "I'm trying to code X, I can't, can you help” isn't a question. Yes we can help — if you ask a specific question, not just issue a general call for unspecified “help”.

Comment: Ok, apologies again if I was being vague. I will get straight to the point, if I wasn't being clear before. Is there a way to get agents to follow or 'help' other agents within a given radius?

Comment: Yes. `in-radius` exists and works (is there a specific technical challenge you've faced with using it?). And "follow" or "help" could mean anything at  all.

Comment: In the interests of trying to refine your question, I downloaded your code from the link specified and tried to run it. I can't - because there's a hard coded link to a non-supplied gif. I can make some assumptions & changes & get the tsunami spreading. As per @SethTisue - you really need to give us a specific problem.  Also - opening an [exact duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266746/netlogo-interaction-between-between-2-turtle-types) is unlikely to have the effect of attracting more people / help and may get you a rather negative response - it's against the rules here.

Comment: A couple of thoughts about ways you might progress. First - you could create a new breed e.g. informed-tourists that initially had no turtles, but tourists could change their breed to that if they were "helped" and that breed could move accordingly. Second - you may be struggling with how to say "if there are any turtles in this radius", in which case - read up on the if any? syntax. Have a go - if you hit problems - edit your question with the exact problem (e.g. error or unexpected behaviour) you see.